# Trim whitespaces and line breaks from a Regex Capture Group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've got the following HTML code:

```
                      <span><b id="PHONE">Phone Number:</b> </span>
                    <span
                      style="margin-left: 8px; color: #1c3452; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 16px;">+32
                      123 45 67 89</span>
                    <br />

<span><b id="EMAIL">Email Address:</b> </span>
                    <span
                      style="margin-left: 8px; color: #1c3452; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 16px;">john.doe@gmail.com/span>
                    <br />
```

With an expression I want to capture the values of the Phone Number and Email Address.
So far for the phone number I tried this:

```
<b id="PHONE">(Phone Number)(\s*):(\s*)<\/b>(\s*)<\/span>(\s*)<span[^>]*>(\s*)(?<Phone>[^<]*)<\/span>
```

It succesfully captures the phone number, but it also grabs the line break and white spaces.

I prepared an example here: https://regex101.com/r/X11veJ/1

Anyone an idea how I can successfully can get the phone number without line breaks and white spaces?
Is this even possible?

I'm pretty much a rookie in regex; so I'm not sure if the written expression is even good.

Appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: why not simply trim the captured value in the program that uses it?

Comment: Only create the groups you want to use. This: `(\s*)` will create a useless group.
What programming language7tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... With an expression I want to capture the values of the Phone Number and Email Address. ...
>
>
>
> ... Anyone an idea how I can successfully can get the phone number without line breaks and white spaces? Is this even possible? ..."*

Use a *capture pattern*.

To preface, you did not specify which *regex engine* you're using, so you may need to adjust the syntax, accordingly.

This will capture the phone number.
The digits are contained within groups *1 through 5*.

```
(?s)id=\"PHONE\">Phone Number:.+?(?:(\+\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+))<\/span>
```

And, this will capture the email address.
Note, the closing *span* tag, after the email address, did not start with a `<` character.
I imagine this may have been a typo, on your behalf.
If not, just leave a comment, and I can re-factor the *pattern*.

```
(?s)id=\"EMAIL\">Email Address:.+?<\/span>.+?>(.+?)<\/span>
```

From here, you can merge both *patterns*, to create a single *pattern*.

```
(?s)id=\"PHONE\">Phone Number:.+?(?:(\+\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+))<\/span>.+?id=\"EMAIL\">Email Address:.+?<\/span>.+?>(.+?)<\/span>
```

Output

```
+32 123 45 67 89
john.doe@gmail.com
```